# DHT22 sensor for RaspberryPi system setup issues

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, adafruit

So I am using a raspberry pi system and am trying to write code in the python to have the system read the humidity and temperature. We are able to get the humidity sensor to read the humidity and temperature in terminal, so we are somewhat sure we set it up right. When we try to import Adafruit_DHT into python (out written code) we get an error when we run the code. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is more info about the code:

Terminal entry:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Adafruit_Python_DHT/examples $ python AdafruitDHT.py 22 4
Temp=24.1*  Humidity=48.4%
```

Python Code:

```
import Adafruit_DHT 

#set sensore type : options are DHT11, DHT22
sensor=Adafruit_DHT.DHT22

#white is 22

#set GPIO sensor is connected to
gpio=4

#use read_retry method, this will retry up to 15 times to get
#a sensor reading (waiting two seconds between each try
humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(sensor, gpio)

#reading the DHT11 is very sensitive to timings and sometimes the Pi might
#fail to get a valid reading (so check)

if humidity is not None and temperature is not None:
    print('Temp={0:0.1f}*C Humidity={1:0.1f}%'.format(temperature, humidity))
else:
    print('Failed to get reading. Try again!')
```

Error from running:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
** IDLE Internal Exception: 
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/idlelib/run.py", line 353, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "/home/pi/hopeful dht run.py", line 1, in <module>
    import Adafruit_DHT
ImportError: No module named 'Adafruit_DHT'
```

Thank you so much!
Izzy

Answer (score 0):

You haven't installed the adafruit_dht library. Need to:

Enter the following in your terminal to install the Adafruit Python DHT Library:

sudo pip3 install Adafruit_DHT

https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-io-basics-temperature-and-humidity/python-setup

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=235179

***if you have done this, and getting the same error, try running python, python2, or python3. You might not have everything updated.